# Post requests: Correct http header syntax?

Tags: post, httpwebrequest, three20

Im using `TTURLRequest` from the cocoa [Three20 development library](http://three20.info/) to form a post request.

I'm setting the http headers with this:

> [request setValue:VALUE
>   forHTTPHeaderField:KEY];

I'm getting a [400](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html) response back.
I'm also using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture the requests and responses. The request is getting out (with the headers I had put in) so obviously I'm not forming the headers correctly or I'm missing some important ones.

The Headers I am setting are:

```
    [request setValue:@"0" 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];//0 length?(not sending any raw data)

    [request setValue:authorizationHeader 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


 [request setValue:@"CUSTOM/1.0" 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

What is the correct syntax and order of http headers in a post request?

Comment: It is difficult to debug without knowing the exact request being sent over the wire, or seeing the authorization header that is being set. It would be best to show more code that demonstrates the problem. Also let us know what auth header you are setting (eg, Basic/Digest etc) without giving the exact header value if there are privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was throwing an exception while doing some custom filtering causing the server to issue a 400 to the client.